# How To auto update angular electron App using electron-updater?

Tags: angular, electron, electron-updater

How To auto update angular electron App using electron-updater?

Nothing How To auto update angular electron App using electron-updater?

Answer (score 0):

**Import autoUpdater**

```
const { autoUpdater} = require('electron');
```

**check for updates, you can check every day using setInterval or when app starting**

```
autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
```

**More check official docs**

https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/updates